# What trick can I use to apply LIMIT for a multiple fetch?

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I don't know if I can do what I expect but hey, at least I can ask you guys...

Here's the thing : I'm building a website with some calendars, and we can add some "dates / rendez vous" on them. For some purpose, I want to get the futur (or actual) closest rendez-vous of each calendars.

I'd like to do it with one query instead of using a loop with one query on each iteration (ie for each calendar), and I want to get only ONE rendez-vous for each calendar and not all the futur ones (which could be... a lot).

So far, I started like that :

```
SELECT p_id, p_cid, p_start, p_end FROM p WHERE p_end >= :date_of_today
```

I was thinking about using LIMIT, but I can't see how to put a LIMIT (like `0,1` for each calendar)...

I guess I will have to use a loop but if someone could give me an other solution :)

**EDIT**

With more informations :

I have a table for calendars, which is like `c_id, c_title, c_owner`, and a table for the rendez-vous, which is like `p_id, p_cid, p_uid, p_start, p_end`.

The rendez-vous can last more than one day. To be more specific, a "rendez-vous" is at least a day : so `p_start` and `p_end` are a date/timestamp like `dd-mm-yyyy 00:00:00`. They can be equal as they can be two differents days.

Comment: Basically you need to rank rows in every calendar according to DESC order and select only top 10 etc. It would be easy with window functions but MySQL does not have them so far. Try to look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql - it is about replacement for rank in MySQL

Comment: How is the set of calendars defined? Please add more details to your question, especially the table definition and the data logic.

Comment: Sorry guys, as you figured out I barrely speak english...
JosMac : I have trouble to understand this "rank rows" thing.. Have to check it deeper, thx for the advice.
 Arkascha : what do you mean by "the set of calendars" ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are looking for the "groupwise minimum". Have a look at [The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html), and add your `where` condition everywhere. There are slightly faster versions of this, but that should be your second concern.

Comment: @Solarflare that sounds very good ! I'll take a look. Thx !